# Ruby Celluloid and resources consumption

Tags: ruby, resources, consumption, celluloid

I'm new to Celluloid and have some questions about pools and futures. I'm building a simple web crawler (see the example at bottom). My URLS array dozen of thousands of URLs, so the example is stripped to some hundred.

What I now want to do is to group to max. 50 req/s using futures, get their callbacks and crawl further 50 urls etc. The problem I have with this code: I would expect that it would maximum 50 threads but it spawns upto 400 and more in my case. If the input data increases, the code snippet finishes because it cannot spawn further requests (OS limits, OSX in my case).

Why are there so many threads spawned and how to avoid this? I need a fast crawler which uses all resources the OS provides but not more than this :) So 2.000 threads seem to be the limit at OSX, all above this value let the code crashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby

require 'celluloid'
require 'open-uri'

URLS = ["http://instagr.am/p/Clh2","http://instagr.am/p/EKpI1","http://instagr.am/p/G-PoDSS6zX","http://instagr.am/p/G5YjYMC4MW","http://instagr.am/p/G6sEojDvgy","http://instagr.am/p/G7LGzIjvMp","http://instagr.am/p/G9RQlkQAc9","http://instagr.am/p/HChQX4SMdy","http://instagr.am/p/HDRNwKojXS","http://instagr.am/p/HDjzB-RYMz","http://instagr.am/p/HDkLCGgSjX","http://instagr.am/p/HE2Xgjj0rn","http://instagr.am/p/HE5M9Lp0MC","http://instagr.am/p/HEW5I2RohI","http://instagr.am/p/HEzv41gS6m","http://instagr.am/p/HG2WCVTQwQ","http://instagr.am/p/HG5XWovFFa","http://instagr.am/p/HGwQvEiSmA","http://instagr.am/p/HH0navKTcf","http://instagr.am/p/HH2OzNQIn8","http://instagr.am/p/HH2kTskO2e","http://instagr.am/p/HH3GaNlTbd","http://instagr.am/p/HH3QbejSMF","http://instagr.am/p/HH3S17HnW5","http://instagr.am/p/HH3dQPqYmJ","http://instagr.am/p/HH3egLxVJU","http://instagr.am/p/HH3nVPS1i0","http://instagr.am/p/HH3zdlB3e-","http://instagr.am/p/HH40eevAr2","http://instagr.am/p/HH49zqInZc","http://instagr.am/p/HH4EMQNnpx","http://instagr.am/p/HH4KCKoc-7","http://instagr.am/p/HH4asXlbpp","http://instagr.am/p/HH4yNBydG2","http://instagr.am/p/HH5M5vCCWu","http://instagr.am/p/HH5MXqLQaz","http://instagr.am/p/HH5YeDpw88","http://instagr.am/p/HH5b89nlyH","http://instagr.am/p/HH61z-Fb-R","http://instagr.am/p/HH68sgJDZZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH69Tlt91p","http://instagr.am/p/HH6BwRgqe4","http://instagr.am/p/HH6E6aGS44","http://instagr.am/p/HH6EEYJgSo","http://instagr.am/p/HH6H7htWJo","http://instagr.am/p/HH6hBRzZZD","http://instagr.am/p/HH6xEExaco","http://instagr.am/p/HH6xcVscEg","http://instagr.am/p/HH70aWB1No","http://instagr.am/p/HH73nUMBMI","http://instagr.am/p/HH74ogvrX5","http://instagr.am/p/HH76mRwZnp","http://instagr.am/p/HH77CPmYE0","http://instagr.am/p/HH78hPNnzQ","http://instagr.am/p/HH7ADox4JO","http://instagr.am/p/HH7KFdOeTE","http://instagr.am/p/HH7KJNGDSG","http://instagr.am/p/HH7KJtpxyA","http://instagr.am/p/HH7KjwpM-J","http://instagr.am/p/HH7Q","http://instagr.am/p/HH7QCiqsOX","http://instagr.am/p/HH7R9er-Oq","http://instagr.am/p/HH7SoqgRYB","http://instagr.am/p/HH7YhZGA75","http://instagr.am/p/HH7aHSJd3D","http://instagr.am/p/HH7bPrMLTB","http://instagr.am/p/HH7bQUnKyn","http://instagr.am/p/HH7c2yADVv","http://instagr.am/p/HH7cEXSCTC","http://instagr.am/p/HH7dxAlxr4","http://instagr.am/p/HH7eJTwO8K","http://instagr.am/p/HH7efCKQ-0","http://instagr.am/p/HH7fczIMyr","http://instagr.am/p/HH7gVnBjad","http://instagr.am/p/HH7gYljc-0","http://instagr.am/p/HH7gYpMKH7","http://instagr.am/p/HH7hDMo_Za","http://instagr.am/p/HH7hfhighk","http://instagr.am/p/HH7hpVm92Q","http://instagr.am/p/HH7hssHUyN","http://instagr.am/p/HH7iS0on88","http://instagr.am/p/HH7j6It5zy","http://instagr.am/p/HH7j75jipU","http://instagr.am/p/HH7j76pkjl","http://instagr.am/p/HH7jMlQLaG","http://instagr.am/p/HH7kHaPbBn","http://instagr.am/p/HH7kKZopDN","http://instagr.am/p/HH7lOFkkOV","http://instagr.am/p/HH7lQtstCP","http://instagr.am/p/HH7l_Aurfu","http://instagr.am/p/HH7m0JDpOC","http://instagr.am/p/HH7m2POzdu","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mHPL0cI","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mL2BdJL","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mN3snzl","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mXJEJIt","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mZAKfdo","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mbxmSnp","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mkHIRM2","http://instagr.am/p/HH7ml5CcLM","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mnxEAJ8","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mqFk38v","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mqtAaOP","http://instagr.am/p/HH7mytlLQm","http://instagr.am/p/HH7n29K0Q1","http://instagr.am/p/HH7naXyW_g","http://instagr.am/p/HH7ncNPJOX","http://instagr.am/p/HH7ndmC0DH","http://instagr.am/p/HH7nifiLCI","http://instagr.am/p/HH7rWttci5","http://instagr.am/p/HH8--LwWs_","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-0DkaPE","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-2CLQEV","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-4gSIJo","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-4liH8g","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-5TCi2b","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-6AKI4j","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-8MtC6l","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-A-gpce","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-A-pXLv","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-BEFQb6","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-C9IxAs","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-CMRIT9","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-DMiDM3","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-Dwg_5V","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-DyHmmX","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-IEnIBo","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-KBCg0f","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-Kbm9Jb","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-LHryjV","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-LIKIXR","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-MdpM-m","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-N9pzfv","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-NbqDLG","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-NwoEwm","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-ODsfzo","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-OHE0p8","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-QFmasl","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-QaA7Rb","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-R-poCB","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-S5PDIy","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-SqHrOY","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-SzPREN","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-U1r5VK","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-UjEeXv","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-VaRadH","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-WFIPij","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-WHRwHP","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-X-SkFA","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-a5icLX","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-aSRpdn","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-aTm5g8","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-aatV6Q","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-azAmc5","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-bcLP_v","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-dGrMku","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-dKABGr","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-eFTTJ8","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-eLRwvK","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-ehmwGz","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-h-D72a","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-hhmEOT","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-ibSZTj","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-jospUb","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-kMpc2F","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-kNBmGm","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-lArilF","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-lWTDwj","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-mNnqZL","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-n4sGGS","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-n9xHbn","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-pYx3JZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-pppok3","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-qoy3LK","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-qvROzb","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-qytoRH","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-rOyW_y","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-s9KXi6","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-sVyS7K","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-sbnQEO","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-txJV-e","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-u0Mewa","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-u1BFJ-","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-uXBu_r","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-ujO2m1","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-v7pm7L","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-vBRADm","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-vkwQNF","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-x5R6u2","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-xArCJB","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-xOxnVQ","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-xrmqCf","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-y4Li29","http://instagr.am/p/HH8-yamwjM","http://instagr.am/p/HH802xDyEm","http://instagr.am/p/HH804Gw-Fe","http://instagr.am/p/HH804hAMqQ","http://instagr.am/p/HH805wBvVI","http://instagr.am/p/HH806SguSx","http://instagr.am/p/HH806rEtcY","http://instagr.am/p/HH809ClkbW","http://instagr.am/p/HH809kPN-5","http://instagr.am/p/HH80Cxst8p","http://instagr.am/p/HH80E3Ibo0","http://instagr.am/p/HH80ELOZpk","http://instagr.am/p/HH80EVFFIz","http://instagr.am/p/HH80FngJs0","http://instagr.am/p/HH80M0kiBG","http://instagr.am/p/HH80cKKQ_E","http://instagr.am/p/HH80gaBUzQ","http://instagr.am/p/HH80lSDT71","http://instagr.am/p/HH80mYOHwX","http://instagr.am/p/HH80nfAYsL","http://instagr.am/p/HH80pUNIO2","http://instagr.am/p/HH80sxRLtt","http://instagr.am/p/HH80vbDjj0","http://instagr.am/p/HH80w7xI-m","http://instagr.am/p/HH80wDHTN4","http://instagr.am/p/HH81-5RjEB","http://instagr.am/p/HH811fo-_e","http://instagr.am/p/HH813tkiVZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH813vkGMo","http://instagr.am/p/HH814RDHuG","http://instagr.am/p/HH814TOYiW","http://instagr.am/p/HH8179vxAg","http://instagr.am/p/HH81AwC6db","http://instagr.am/p/HH81BGyWUr","http://instagr.am/p/HH81FoFjxm","http://instagr.am/p/HH81H-IH_i","http://instagr.am/p/HH81MnoSaI","http://instagr.am/p/HH81MtN3bH","http://instagr.am/p/HH81O1Cfe7","http://instagr.am/p/HH81RprFKO","http://instagr.am/p/HH81Z2pq3V","http://instagr.am/p/HH81aCPRem","http://instagr.am/p/HH81aVTWZm","http://instagr.am/p/HH81bBo8cM","http://instagr.am/p/HH81k2xVJ4","http://instagr.am/p/HH81kERlbh","http://instagr.am/p/HH81vqHC0M","http://instagr.am/p/HH81vqyti3","http://instagr.am/p/HH81wbS-cj","http://instagr.am/p/HH81xfEjvZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH81zsrbsz","http://instagr.am/p/HH823tDEIP","http://instagr.am/p/HH823ytt2P","http://instagr.am/p/HH825MgnYc","http://instagr.am/p/HH827QrTPF","http://instagr.am/p/HH82AWzhzS","http://instagr.am/p/HH82EGE05q","http://instagr.am/p/HH82FDu8Mf","http://instagr.am/p/HH82HTmdze","http://instagr.am/p/HH82L-iG-U","http://instagr.am/p/HH82NpFsn7","http://instagr.am/p/HH82YTOqEF","http://instagr.am/p/HH82bpEdvj","http://instagr.am/p/HH82cShmmV","http://instagr.am/p/HH82czP-SU","http://instagr.am/p/HH82h9LhYy","http://instagr.am/p/HH82iizf4G","http://instagr.am/p/HH82jUw184","http://instagr.am/p/HH82mrnPeW","http://instagr.am/p/HH82t9u8Mg","http://instagr.am/p/HH82tPH1El","http://instagr.am/p/HH82wzhczs","http://instagr.am/p/HH82zzjj7W","http://instagr.am/p/HH83-3oaAb","http://instagr.am/p/HH83-AlcOq","http://instagr.am/p/HH8302rtlY","http://instagr.am/p/HH833ty-ck","http://instagr.am/p/HH834lswSl","http://instagr.am/p/HH835DFp5j","http://instagr.am/p/HH835FKCBP","http://instagr.am/p/HH835UmKXt","http://instagr.am/p/HH835qnQot","http://instagr.am/p/HH8383zIXz","http://instagr.am/p/HH8384ROzS","http://instagr.am/p/HH83AMP4a0","http://instagr.am/p/HH83B5B1Nt","http://instagr.am/p/HH83CqkA0O","http://instagr.am/p/HH83DpMRPq","http://instagr.am/p/HH83EjPNA_","http://instagr.am/p/HH83Frqolx","http://instagr.am/p/HH83KmM8EC","http://instagr.am/p/HH83RJuxBF","http://instagr.am/p/HH83WCuGEA","http://instagr.am/p/HH83XtGGIV","http://instagr.am/p/HH83ZKNcTS","http://instagr.am/p/HH83aNohKe","http://instagr.am/p/HH83bCudp9","http://instagr.am/p/HH83f0vFsx","http://instagr.am/p/HH83gsmWCm","http://instagr.am/p/HH83gyJWp5","http://instagr.am/p/HH83k0h0C3","http://instagr.am/p/HH83nDlyBo","http://instagr.am/p/HH83nSlA26","http://instagr.am/p/HH83nfnS7m","http://instagr.am/p/HH83puJ0UJ","http://instagr.am/p/HH83qGPaXH","http://instagr.am/p/HH83r9D_FK","http://instagr.am/p/HH83uAFKtr","http://instagr.am/p/HH83uJxZeV","http://instagr.am/p/HH83vcTWsX","http://instagr.am/p/HH83xtmDSU","http://instagr.am/p/HH841GGzT3","http://instagr.am/p/HH841UMarm","http://instagr.am/p/HH841VgcD4","http://instagr.am/p/HH8429HDTT","http://instagr.am/p/HH842SMBUn","http://instagr.am/p/HH842cRA6V","http://instagr.am/p/HH842nNboH","http://instagr.am/p/HH844ISVI_","http://instagr.am/p/HH844QPBbt","http://instagr.am/p/HH8460RADl","http://instagr.am/p/HH846VkDLB","http://instagr.am/p/HH846jSV9B","http://instagr.am/p/HH847YpeiM","http://instagr.am/p/HH848JoFPh","http://instagr.am/p/HH849dRQnD","http://instagr.am/p/HH84EBB-rW","http://instagr.am/p/HH84GXHQEN","http://instagr.am/p/HH84IOO6Hd","http://instagr.am/p/HH84K7vdZp","http://instagr.am/p/HH84O1vefu","http://instagr.am/p/HH84O2hj7y","http://instagr.am/p/HH84OALIqP","http://instagr.am/p/HH84PVk-tn","http://instagr.am/p/HH84RquusO","http://instagr.am/p/HH84TnhJKv","http://instagr.am/p/HH84WQH1En","http://instagr.am/p/HH84XPiGqI","http://instagr.am/p/HH84YLH5ty","http://instagr.am/p/HH84YpLGfC","http://instagr.am/p/HH84Ywvdk6","http://instagr.am/p/HH84ZdzhTA","http://instagr.am/p/HH84afzC-V","http://instagr.am/p/HH84ctJ5s1","http://instagr.am/p/HH84dTHX9F","http://instagr.am/p/HH84fXPKi5","http://instagr.am/p/HH84fhto0L","http://instagr.am/p/HH84geJyhL","http://instagr.am/p/HH84hUpz82","http://instagr.am/p/HH84iYKYQp","http://instagr.am/p/HH84kFDSyv","http://instagr.am/p/HH84nNH_1J","http://instagr.am/p/HH84o1D3Um","http://instagr.am/p/HH84ohtzcL","http://instagr.am/p/HH84pNDJcd","http://instagr.am/p/HH84pOH6TN","http://instagr.am/p/HH84pXMYZd","http://instagr.am/p/HH84qkJ0i3","http://instagr.am/p/HH84sTvixj","http://instagr.am/p/HH84tan8wH","http://instagr.am/p/HH84w1gm7Z","http://instagr.am/p/HH84yNv-z-","http://instagr.am/p/HH84zAoMEl","http://instagr.am/p/HH85-0RTj8","http://instagr.am/p/HH850YgA3T","http://instagr.am/p/HH850pPNBB","http://instagr.am/p/HH850tOWXm","http://instagr.am/p/HH851nnMar","http://instagr.am/p/HH851yhV8o","http://instagr.am/p/HH852bqPAx","http://instagr.am/p/HH852nDatV","http://instagr.am/p/HH852pxXn5","http://instagr.am/p/HH853TsOYx","http://instagr.am/p/HH854_ob--","http://instagr.am/p/HH854kL_yC","http://instagr.am/p/HH8563jp99","http://instagr.am/p/HH856HhpBi","http://instagr.am/p/HH857CEjxZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH857URkql","http://instagr.am/p/HH857UqVCN","http://instagr.am/p/HH8580SWLd","http://instagr.am/p/HH858wITqb","http://instagr.am/p/HH85AXKxP5","http://instagr.am/p/HH85CIL_yB","http://instagr.am/p/HH85CKCp4U","http://instagr.am/p/HH85DLn-09","http://instagr.am/p/HH85Dnljqy","http://instagr.am/p/HH85E0Jcj3","http://instagr.am/p/HH85EKR9fm","http://instagr.am/p/HH85EgBaHm","http://instagr.am/p/HH85ElD4b_","http://instagr.am/p/HH85HBm9f4","http://instagr.am/p/HH85HFrCl3","http://instagr.am/p/HH85JYunBd","http://instagr.am/p/HH85LVoMhr","http://instagr.am/p/HH85LWCbeC","http://instagr.am/p/HH85MKFbQt","http://instagr.am/p/HH85NJv80J","http://instagr.am/p/HH85NUvTvk","http://instagr.am/p/HH85NyufqK","http://instagr.am/p/HH85PZOR6d","http://instagr.am/p/HH85Q2M2uh","http://instagr.am/p/HH85T2Ofcs","http://instagr.am/p/HH85VUKVTZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH85VVKoly","http://instagr.am/p/HH85VdK6R1","http://instagr.am/p/HH85Vfmn0-","http://instagr.am/p/HH85VxIOrP","http://instagr.am/p/HH85WoR6Ls","http://instagr.am/p/HH85Ztrf-m","http://instagr.am/p/HH85aLrxjq","http://instagr.am/p/HH85bOR6u0","http://instagr.am/p/HH85cZLXr6","http://instagr.am/p/HH85ckD-JY","http://instagr.am/p/HH85d6JlSW","http://instagr.am/p/HH85dUwcKY","http://instagr.am/p/HH85fUuT6W","http://instagr.am/p/HH85fiAaOe","http://instagr.am/p/HH85gMJBEP","http://instagr.am/p/HH85gVFvEt","http://instagr.am/p/HH85hIveqD","http://instagr.am/p/HH85hZAKiO","http://instagr.am/p/HH85i8CyMs","http://instagr.am/p/HH85jQhUo7","http://instagr.am/p/HH85kBSD2v","http://instagr.am/p/HH85lsFy6K","http://instagr.am/p/HH85mLnJky","http://instagr.am/p/HH85oVROzU","http://instagr.am/p/HH85p9ylU4","http://instagr.am/p/HH85qENCWv","http://instagr.am/p/HH85qhNMcj","http://instagr.am/p/HH85s3N7vl","http://instagr.am/p/HH85sJSPSe","http://instagr.am/p/HH85tStObP","http://instagr.am/p/HH85txnKmv","http://instagr.am/p/HH85uAvobc","http://instagr.am/p/HH85x8rlE0","http://instagr.am/p/HH85xZuNO8","http://instagr.am/p/HH85yYQwXj","http://instagr.am/p/HH85z3wB35","http://instagr.am/p/HH86-kGL7D","http://instagr.am/p/HH860TiUwo","http://instagr.am/p/HH861PIkO2","http://instagr.am/p/HH862smvKU","http://instagr.am/p/HH863NxVJ5","http://instagr.am/p/HH863Zw3Z2","http://instagr.am/p/HH865_H-sk","http://instagr.am/p/HH865nxSRn","http://instagr.am/p/HH868cli0X","http://instagr.am/p/HH86AKRtq-","http://instagr.am/p/HH86CjRQTU","http://instagr.am/p/HH86D8sx0Q","http://instagr.am/p/HH86DqzgPd","http://instagr.am/p/HH86EkSO83","http://instagr.am/p/HH86FzO4D_","http://instagr.am/p/HH86G8MkDx","http://instagr.am/p/HH86GGwXA0","http://instagr.am/p/HH86Hwq8Nu","http://instagr.am/p/HH86HzG4HB","http://instagr.am/p/HH86HzJtHN","http://instagr.am/p/HH86IMLZYc","http://instagr.am/p/HH86IXyAMV","http://instagr.am/p/HH86IwQ8Qk","http://instagr.am/p/HH86KXQuR6","http://instagr.am/p/HH86LTkJJE","http://instagr.am/p/HH86NrLH5g","http://instagr.am/p/HH86SWRNOm","http://instagr.am/p/HH86TJI64M","http://instagr.am/p/HH86TtpBEQ","http://instagr.am/p/HH86UYKOhh","http://instagr.am/p/HH86VGlnpW","http://instagr.am/p/HH86ZfpEEw","http://instagr.am/p/HH86_NPrK2","http://instagr.am/p/HH86afDy4x","http://instagr.am/p/HH86afyFIQ","http://instagr.am/p/HH86bGLfNe","http://instagr.am/p/HH86btlKts","http://instagr.am/p/HH86c9u8Wq","http://instagr.am/p/HH86cSR3_L","http://instagr.am/p/HH86fEHdLt","http://instagr.am/p/HH86g5m-xm","http://instagr.am/p/HH86gKCqXT","http://instagr.am/p/HH86gQGfPG","http://instagr.am/p/HH86hlSkE9","http://instagr.am/p/HH86hzhSep","http://instagr.am/p/HH86inFZGd","http://instagr.am/p/HH86ipACWp","http://instagr.am/p/HH86jXw0gP","http://instagr.am/p/HH86l3lWdw","http://instagr.am/p/HH86lBIcoK","http://instagr.am/p/HH86lbyhFP","http://instagr.am/p/HH86maiG-V","http://instagr.am/p/HH86mgqMW3","http://instagr.am/p/HH86mqFBiB","http://instagr.am/p/HH86mwm5g5","http://instagr.am/p/HH86oeJWA2","http://instagr.am/p/HH86ofFMPU","http://instagr.am/p/HH86ohOsAZ","http://instagr.am/p/HH86olHu0A","http://instagr.am/p/HH86otvR1t","http://instagr.am/p/HH86pHTMXp","http://instagr.am/p/HH86qENjaU","http://instagr.am/p/HH86rtCd4L","http://instagr.am/p/HH86s0N3Ay","http://instagr.am/p/HH86sDPkW6","http://instagr.am/p/HH86tLMj5x"]

class Crawler
  include Celluloid

  def fetch(id)
    uri = URI("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=#{id}")
    req = open(uri).read
  end
end

URLS.each_slice(50).map do |idset|
  pool = Crawler.pool(size: 50)
  crawlers = idset.to_a.map do |id|
    begin
      pool.future(:fetch, id)
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end
  crawlers.compact.each do |resp|
    puts resp.value.size rescue nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Split the class. It's been told on wiki to never do pool of a worker inside it.

https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Pools

> Gotcha: Don't make pools inside workers!
>
> Using MyWorker.pool within MyWorker will result in an unbounded
>   explosion of worker threads.

---

## Update

If you want to limit your pool just create it outside the each_slice block so you use always the same Threads I guess.

```
pool = Crawler.pool(size: 50)    
URLS.each_slice(50).map do |idset|  
  crawlers = idset.to_a.map do |id|
    begin
      pool.future(:fetch, id)
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end
# ...
```

Comment: Hm, I don't see where I make a pool inside a worker. Crawler doesnt spawn a pool, I'm creating the pool outside of it. The wiki explains no to use .pool within class Crawler, right?

Comment: I guess you might be right. But then I don't know what might be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration through the slice of 50 you're resetting the value of pool, which likely is dereferencing your poolmanager. Since actors aren't garbage collected just by being dereferenced (you have to call #terminate) you're probably piling up your old pools. It *should* be ok to just make one pool, and create all your futures at once (if you keep the return value small the future object itself is small). If you do find that you have to slice, instantiate your pool outside the each_slice and it will continue to use the same pool without making a new one each time around. If for some other reason you want to get a new pool each time, call terminate on the pool before you dereference it. Also be sure you're working with celluloid 0.12.0+ as it fixes an issue where pool workers weren't being terminated when the pool was.

When I iterate around actors, I've found this bit of logging to be useful to be sure I don't have any actor leaks:

```
logger.info "Actors left: #{Celluloid::Actor.all.to_set.length} Alive: #{Celluloid::Actor.all.to_set.reject { |a| a.nil? || !a.alive? }.length}"
```